# How would you create a unique index on a foreign table?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

Database 1 has foreign tables a and b on database 2.

How can we create indexes on these foreign tables a and b. These foreign tables are wrappers over database2.c and database2.d tables respectively, which do have the necessary indexes in place.

How would you create indexes on foreign tables a and b? Is that even possible?

I get a cannot create index on foreign table a - when I try a simple Create Index command in postgres

Comment: why would you want such thing? If tables have UK on database2, why would you want to have them in databse1?.. They already have a unique constraint?..

Comment: Hmmm may be you can take a look at this question for more context - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803345/deleting-rows-which-do-not-have-entries-in-another-table-as-foreign-keys-takes-a?noredirect=1#comment68896624_40803345

Comment: so it's postgres-9.4 then. Foreign tables query planning for optimizer is indeed very limited with 9.4 (and 9.5 as well). I know 9.5 fdw offers remote joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create index on a foreign table, instead write a trigger on foreign table and create a local table in postgres such that whenever an insert, update or delete is happening in your foreign table it will be reflected in your local table and index it.

Comment: My local tables have indexes. I am not sure I completely understand what you are saying

Comment: create local table with same structure of your foreign table, write a trigger such that whatever data comes into your foreign table is replicated in your local table. You can add index to your local table

Comment: I have accepted your answer  but frankly I am using postgres_fdw and insert queries to insert data to my local tables. These do not even need foreign tables.

Comment: It's just the delete that I need

Answer (score 4):

Joining with a foreign table can result to slow query's. 
Since indexes are not a option with foreign table, consider making a materialized view on a foreign table . Materialized views do allow indexing

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE members_fdw(...)

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW members AS 
       select * from members_fdw  
       WITH  DATA 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "member_id" ON members USING btree ("id");
```